# Buttons scrolling the gallery

Tags: android, button, callback, gallery, onfling

In my application I have a `Gallery` view and two buttons to scroll it - left and right. Scrolling the gallery by fling also works, and here is the problem: how can I update the states of buttons after the user scrolled the `Gallery` using fling movements? Is there any callback that tells that `Gallery`'s selected item has changed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [onItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) that you can use with a gallery. If you use it you'll probably also want to read about [setCallbackDuringFling()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html#setCallbackDuringFling%28boolean%29) that can enable/disable the listener while flinging.